# Android Accelerometer coding not working for all mobiles

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors

I am in the process of developing Android music player which will do the the following actions once a shake action is detected
Actions
1. Do Nothing
2. Play or Pause
3. Next Song
4. Previous Song

I have created a Service class for the shaking action and it is as follows.

```
public class Shaker extends Service implements SensorEventListener {

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private static final int MIN_TIME_BETWEEN_SHAKES_MILLISECS = 1000;
    private long mLastShakeTime;
    private SensorManager sensorManager;
    private static final String SHAKE_ACTION_PREFERENCE = "shake_action_preference";
    private static final String SHAKE_THRESHOLD_PREFERENCE = "shake_threshold_preference";
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    public void onCreate() {

        sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        super.onCreate();
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensorManager
                .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensorManager
                .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if ((curTime - mLastShakeTime) > MIN_TIME_BETWEEN_SHAKES_MILLISECS) {

                float x = event.values[0];
                float y = event.values[1];
                float z = event.values[2];

                double acceleration = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x, 2) +
                        Math.pow(y, 2) +
                        Math.pow(z, 2)) - SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH;
                Log.d("Acceleration", "Acceleration is " + acceleration + "m/s^2");

                String threshold = sharedPreferences.getString(SHAKE_THRESHOLD_PREFERENCE, "medium");

                float SHAKE_THRESHOLD;
                if(threshold.equals("high"))
                    SHAKE_THRESHOLD = 40.5f;
                else if(threshold.equals("low"))
                    SHAKE_THRESHOLD = 15.5f;
                else
                    SHAKE_THRESHOLD = 25.5f;
                if (acceleration > SHAKE_THRESHOLD) {
                    mLastShakeTime = curTime;
                    Log.d("Shake", "Shake, Rattle, and Roll");

                    String opt = sharedPreferences.getString(SHAKE_ACTION_PREFERENCE, "nothing");
                    Log.d("SharedPreference", opt);
                    Log.d("SharedPreference", threshold);
                    if(opt.equals("play")) {
                        MusicPlayer.playOrPause();
                    } else if(opt.equals("next")) {
                        MusicPlayer.next();
                    } else if(opt.equals("prev")) {
                        MusicPlayer.previous(getApplicationContext(), false);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when i run the apk files in actual devices,the shaking function is working only on certain phones and not working for all the mobiles.

I have tried on different mobiles using same Android OS, but it is working in one and not working in the other

I couldnt figure out why it is like this. Can anybody suggest a solution for this?.

Comment: What exactly happens on the devices where it doesn't work? Does the LogCat contain the "Aceleration is ..." entry?

Comment: I am running the apk files on the actual device not on the AVD emulator. In the actual device i cannot see the LogCat, right?

Comment: You can, in debug mode, you have access to it.

Comment: Of course you can see the LogCat of real devices! See https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html#systemLogView

Comment: I will check the logcat and will let you know

Comment: Hi I checked the log cat no such entry "Acceleration is...."